# How do I hook up sink to offset drain

Tags: plumbing

I have an IKEA cabinet that is going to have a sink in it. On the bottom, there is a drawer, for pulling out the garbage can, etc.  As you can see from:

[image]

the drain line doesn't line up with the centerline of the sink.  From this second photo:

[image]

You can see that the drawer is at the same height as the drain.  This prevents simply putting the P-trap at the same height as the drain and using a 45 on the drain to get over to the P-trap.

My question is, how do connect from the drain to the sink, given that the drain does not line up directly and the moving shelf would be in the way.

Also, it would be nice to have some sort of cleanout (maybe with a wye??) where the drain comes out of the wall so that I can clean out the pipes with minimal amount of turns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is run the p-trap parallel to the back wall within the space between the wall and the back of the drawer.

If there is adequate space, start with a wye directly onto the pipe as it comes out of the wall with a line cleanout glued into the end of the wye (if there isn't enough space, use a 45 elbow). Use a fitting 45 or regular 45 elbow (again, depending on the available space) into the side outlet of the wye, then a short piece of pipe and the p-trap. Now you can go vertical along the back wall, then use two 90 elbows to offset to the sink's tail piece.

Comment: IKEA's sinks come with a tailpiece that takes a quick 90-ish angle to the back of the cabinet.  So they don't interfere with the drawers.
Once you're clear of the back of the drawer, you can elbow down and join up sideways with the trap.

Answer (score 0):

Just get a flex pipe p-trap or use some extra bends, 45 degree, although I bet fles would be best unless you actually have a 45 degree offset.